# SQL - grouping some rows as a single row but not others

Tags: grouping

I have a table containing the following fields:

Location, WeekEnded and SalesOrder

I would like to sum by Location but there are several locations that only have a small number of orders that I would like to Group Together as a single location, I just cannot seem to get the code correct.

Curent Results

- Location A    55
- Location B    66
- Location C      1
- etc           11

What I would like is

- Location A  55
- Location B  66
- Location C-Z 12

Code at the moment is

```
SELECT
       Location,
       WeekEnd,
       sum(SOCount) as 'Sales Orders'

FROM  SalesOrderHist
GROUP BY 
       Location,
       WeekEnd
```

Anyone that can help I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE in your GROUP BY clause

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks Adish but unfortunately locations C to Z still came up on separate rows.  What I am trying to achieve is for them to appear on one row renamed Location C-Z.

Comment: Issue resolved.  I created a subquery with a  case statement.

Comment: @Murrayk - You could do the same without a subquery as well. Could you please post your final code as an "answer"? That will help the next guy with the same problem.

Comment: @Ahmed - I understand this is not a complete answer, but is it not better to drop hints and let the user work on it rather than spoon feed by giving a complete query?

Answer (score 0):

Final code, in case this may help someone.  The code contained quite a bit more so I have narrowed it down to include just the important stuff.  I am a bit new to SQL so there may be a more effective way but this worked for me.

```js
SELECT
lname as Location,
WeekStart as 'Week Start',
SOCount

FROM 
(
SELECT
    WeekStart,
    SOCount,
    CASE 
       when cast(lname as varchar(40)) in ('Location A') then 'Location A'
       when cast(lname as varchar(40)) in  ('Location B') then 'Location B' 
       when cast(lname as varchar(40)) =  'Location C' then 'Location C' 
       when cast(lname as varchar(40)) not in ('Location A','Location B','Location C') then 'OTHER' 
       else cast(lname as varchar(40)) 
       end as lname
     FROM
        BDO_salesorderhist_pickeddate2
     GROUP BY 
         lname
) d

GROUP BY
lname
```